# how to remove widgets without a global variable when using a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a couple of widgets that appear when my code first runs, but when I press a button it all disappears and other widgets pop up. I also have a back button that then retrieves the widgets that are removed and remove the second set of widgets. My issue is that I am using a global variable in order for the widgets to be removed, and I want to know what is a better way to approach this without using global variables? I also get weak warnings about the global variables not being defined at the modular level.

```
from tkinter import *  # allows for the use of tkinter GUI

win = Tk()  # creates the tkinter window
win.geometry("1270x725+0+0")


def something_happens(e1, e2, e3):
    print('something is supposed to happen when an option is pressed but that\'s not important')


def category_option_menu():
    global category_drop_down_menu
    global category_variable
    category_names = ['all', 'electrical', 'mechanical', 'optics']  # sets the names of the different categories that
    # will sort the items so only those items show up
    category_variable = StringVar(win)
    category_variable.set(category_names[0])

    category_drop_down_menu = OptionMenu(win, category_variable, *category_names)  # creates the option menu for the
    # different categories
    category_drop_down_menu.config(width=10, font=('Arial', 20), highlightthickness=0)  # sets the parameters
    category_drop_down_menu.place(relx=.45, rely=.3)  # moves the option_menu to its location
    category_variable.trace('w', something_happens)  # if any option in the option menu is pressed, the CategoryChanged
    # function will run


def destroy_widget():
    category_drop_down_menu.place(relx=2)


button = Button(win, text='this is suppose to get rid of the option menu widget', font=('Arial', 20),
                command=destroy_widget)
button.place(relx=.2, rely=.5)


category_option_menu()


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: use classes, the thing about not defined in module level is because outside the functions in the global scope there is not a variable, it is first initialized in the function

Comment: Basically `win` is global too, can you avoid that in this procedural approach? If you want to get rid of globalized variables, then use OOP. And technically, you are not destroying any widgets, you are just "hiding" it